# How to modify Chart legends in Excel 2013

Tags: charts, legend, excel-2013

I am trying to create a chart in Excel 2013 from a subset of data within a larger report.  All the examples show using the headers to create the legend on the chart, but since I am just using select rows in the report, I can't utilize the headers.  Is there any way to directly modify the legend, or even indirectly.  I am open to any suggestions.  Basically, I have a row with multiple data points that I want to graph.  The title works out okay, but the legend just indicates 1 and 7 (the columns I am charting).  Since I don't want to graph the entire report, I don't seem to be able to capture the column headings.

Comment: Could you provide a visual of what you have at the moment and what you're after?

Answer (score 2):

The words in the legend are sourced from the series name. You can point the series name to any cell in the spreadsheet. In the screenshot, the original series names were `one`, `two` and `three`. In the series definition, they got re-pointed to the cells that say `blue`, `red` and `green`.

[image]

Depending on your data and requirements this can be made dynamic.

Comment: OK, now how did you get to that screen to be able to take those strings as legends?

Comment: Right-click any column in the chart and select "Select Data" in the context menu. In the next dialog, select one of the series and click the Edit button.

Comment: Thanks ... U may add the comment in main answer :)